# C++ program crashing due to seemingly unrelated array

Tags: c++

I'm developing a terrain generator in OpenGL and encounter a strange bug. I can define how long the triangles that the terrain is made from are like this:

```
#define TRIANGLE_WIDTH 0.25f 
#define INVERSE_TRIANGLE_WIDTH 4
```

With those sizes I create arrays, that are used to store the data of the terrain. I have made some typedefs for the array that look like this:

```
typedef std::array<std::array<glm::vec3, CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT>, CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT> MapDataVec3Type;
typedef std::array<std::array<glm::vec2, CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT>, CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT> MapDataVec2Type;
```

I am using OpenGLs index based rendering. To minimize memory use I automatically calculate if `unsigned shorts` are sufficient or if I need `unsigned ints` like this:

```
#define CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT (CHUNK_WIDTH * INVERSE_TRIANGLE_WIDTH)
#define CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT_FLOAT (float)(CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT)
#define CHUNK_ARRAY_SIZE CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT * CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT


#if CHUNK_ARRAY_SIZE >= 65535
#define MAP_INDICES_ARRAY_TYPE unsigned int
#define MAP_INDICES_ARRAY_GL_TYPE GL_UNSIGNED_INT
#else
#define MAP_INDICES_ARRAY_TYPE unsigned short
#define MAP_INDICES_ARRAY_GL_TYPE GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT
#endif
```

This all works but when the `TRIANGLE_WIDTH` gets smaller then `0.125` I get a crash when running the program.

I am using Xcode and whenever a program crashes, Xcode shows me where the error is in the assembly code:

```
SDL-OpenGL-Tests-3`main:
    0x100030760 <+0>:     pushq  %rbp
    0x100030761 <+1>:     movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100030764 <+4>:     subq   $0x807f60, %rsp           ; imm = 0x807F60 
    0x10003076b <+11>:    movq   0x5b936(%rip), %rax       ; (void *)0x00007fff92ccdd40: __stack_chk_guard
    0x100030772 <+18>:    movq   (%rax), %rax
    0x100030775 <+21>:    movq   %rax, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x100030779 <+25>:    movl   $0x0, -0x291c(%rbp)
    0x100030783 <+35>:    movl   %edi, -0x2920(%rbp)
    0x100030789 <+41>:    movq   %rsi, -0x2928(%rbp)
    0x100030790 <+48>:    leaq   0x4357b(%rip), %rsi       ; "/dev/urandom"
    0x100030797 <+55>:    leaq   -0x2948(%rbp), %rax
    0x10003079e <+62>:    movq   %rax, %rdi
->  0x1000307a1 <+65>:    movq   %rax, -0x807178(%rbp)
    0x1000307a8 <+72>:    callq  0x100030090               ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::nullptr_t> at string:817
    0x1000307ad <+77>:    leaq   -0x2930(%rbp), %rdi
```

The error is marked by the arrow. From my limited knowledge of assembly I think this part is corespondent to the start of my `int main()` that looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::random_device randomDevice;
    std::mt19937 randomEngine(randomDevice());

    bool capFps = true;
    int fpsCap = 60;
    double frameTimeCap = double(1e6) / double(fpsCap);
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start, end;


    std::cout << "Main Thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
```

I really don't get how my terrain generation is affecting the random functions of C++ since I don't use the random engine in my terrain generation, I use it to randomly place some light sources.

**Update:**

Because elsamuko pointed out that I should interchange the C++ random function with some pseudo random number I removed the random functions and now just set all the random values to zero and it still crashes now with this code:

```
SDL-OpenGL-Tests-3`main:
    0x10002fc30 <+0>:     pushq  %rbp
    0x10002fc31 <+1>:     movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10002fc34 <+4>:     subq   $0x807510, %rsp           ; imm = 0x807510 
    0x10002fc3b <+11>:    movsd  0x5aacd(%rip), %xmm0      ; typeinfo name for Sphere + 12, xmm0 = mem[0],zero 
    0x10002fc43 <+19>:    movq   0x5c45e(%rip), %rax       ; (void *)0x00007fff92ccdd40: __stack_chk_guard
    0x10002fc4a <+26>:    movq   (%rax), %rax
    0x10002fc4d <+29>:    movq   %rax, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x10002fc51 <+33>:    movl   $0x0, -0x291c(%rbp)
    0x10002fc5b <+43>:    movl   %edi, -0x2920(%rbp)
    0x10002fc61 <+49>:    movq   %rsi, -0x2928(%rbp)
    0x10002fc68 <+56>:    movb   $0x1, -0x2929(%rbp)
    0x10002fc6f <+63>:    movl   $0x3c, -0x2930(%rbp)
    0x10002fc79 <+73>:    cvtsi2sdl -0x2930(%rbp), %xmm1
    0x10002fc81 <+81>:    divsd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    0x10002fc85 <+85>:    movsd  %xmm0, -0x2938(%rbp)
    0x10002fc8d <+93>:    leaq   -0x2940(%rbp), %rdi
->  0x10002fc94 <+100>:   callq  0x100038310               ; std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >::time_point at chrono:1338
    0x10002fc99 <+105>:   leaq   -0x2948(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10002fca0 <+112>:   callq  0x100038310               ; std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >::time_point at chrono:1338
    0x10002fca5 <+117>:   movq   0x5c384(%rip), %rdi       ; (void *)0x00007fff92814760: std::__1::cout
    0x10002fcac <+124>:   leaq   0x44007(%rip), %rsi       ; "Main Thread ID: "
    0x10002fcb3 <+131>:   callq  0x10007132c               ; symbol stub for: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
```

It seems as the code just pics the first command it gets to crash.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211937/discussion-on-question-by-user11914177-c-program-crashing-due-to-seemingly-unr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is due to a stack overflow that occurs when the gets too large. The simplest solution is to use a `std::unique_ptr`, because this array will be allocated on the heap.